# junit test for apache CommandLineParser example

Tags: java, junit, apache-commons

Here is an example code using apache CommandLineParser

```
public class Foo {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    Options options = new Options();

    options.addOption("x",
            true, "comment for param x");

    options.addOption("y",
            true, "comment for param y");


    CommandLine commandLine = null;

    CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();

    try {
        commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing arguments!");
    }

    if (!commandLine.hasOption("x")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("x"
                + " option is missing!");
    }

    String numberOfColumns = commandLine.getOptionValue("x");
 :
 :

}
```

JUNIT test code:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() throws Exception {

    args = new String[2];

    args[0] = "x" + "=" + "hello";

    args[1] = "y" + "=" + "world";

    Foo.main(args);

}
```

My problem/question:

CommandLineParser keeps complaining that "x option is missing!". So I believe, the way I am passing the parameter and its values to command line parser is wrong. I  tried other ways as well.

```
    args[0] = "-x" + "=" + "hello";
    args[1] = "-y" + "=" + "world";
```

and also

```
    args[0] = "x" 
    args[1] = "hello";
    args[2] = "y" 
    args[3] = "world";
```

Can some one, tell me the correct format to pass the arguments and its values so as to succeed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd ask myself, am I testing my code or Apache's? The point of having a unit test is to make sure future developers don't break something. It seems like you're are only testing how the cmi is configured. In the future, when someone changes how this is configured, what dose the unit test failing prove?

Comment: I have my application which is using Apache's CommandLineParser example. I am able to successfully test it manually (via terminal). Since I have junit test cases where I have to pass the parameters via args[], so I needed the correct format to pass the params and values via junit.

Comment: It's prefectly right that you are testing the parsing of the command-line arguments.

Comment: @StefanBirkner It's a waste of time, really. Lets say you write a unit test to make sure you configure it correctly (which is valid, but so is adhoc testing). At that point, however, you might as well delete it. Any change that breaks this test would have been deliberate.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to test if configuration you make on command line is correctly set in your config model (e.g. config.getX().equals("hello")). And maybe test if the sanity checks were correct, let's assume y should be an integer greater than 12.

Comment: I guess we can agree that I disagree with the majority. I'd agree that you need to test that assumptions about the resulting input (making sure that an exception is thrown when you expect a value greater than 12). But writing unit tests for what a 3rd party library is doing... A library that has been proven for years... okay, guys.. test your little hearts out.

Comment: If the junit test for the application has to validate the output (based on its business logic), then it has to pass the input parameters in the correct format otherwise, CommandLineParser will error out causing the junit test of the application to fail. Stefan Birkner's input below helped - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the arguments must start with a minus.

```
args[0] = "-x";
args[1] = "hello";
args[2] = "-y";
args[3] = "world";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this following to test input:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

The following shows examples of the of different inputs

INPUT: *-x=hello -y=world*

```
args[0]="-x=hello"
args[1]="-x=world"
```

INPUT: *-x hello -y world*

```
args[0]="-x"
args[1]="hello"
args[2]="-y"
args[3]="-world"
```